# How do I wait for a callback to resolve a promise in JS? Sync iOS WKWebView and JS

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, wkwebview

Recently I have been trying to implement my own `LocalStorage` implementation but instead of storing data in JS I'm trying to store data on iOS native side in `NSUserDefaults`. I will show u some code to make clear what I'm talking about. I have such method for my own `LocalStorage` prototype:

```
Storage.prototype.getItem = (function (key) {
    var that = this;
    var getValue = (function () {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // JS2Native request value for a specific key
            sendWebKitMessage(LS_GET_ITEM, { key: key });
                           
            console.log("new Promise for key=" + key + " timeInMs=" + Date.now());

            // create success callback
            that.onKeyValueReceived = function (keyValuePair) {
                if (keyValuePair !== null) {
                    console.log("onKeyValueReceived=" + keyValuePair.key + " value=" + keyValuePair.value);
                    resolve(keyValuePair.value);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("onKeyValueReceived=null for=" + key);
                    resolve(null);
                }
            };
        });
    });

    // handle async response from the Native side
    var waitFuntion = (async function () {
        var value = await getValue();
        console.log("value="+value);
        return value;
    });
    return waitFuntion();
});

// Native2JS helper methods
Storage.prototype.pasKeyValuePair = function (key, value) {
    this.onKeyValueReceived(key, value);
};
```

In `getItem` I assume that when a client is calling it, it will wait until the iOS native side will get this value from `NSUserDefaults` and pass it to Storage via `Storage.prototype.pasKeyValuePair` method.

But actually it look like that when `sendWebKitMessage(LS_GET_ITEM, { key: key })` is called the 'thread' is not blocked and the client can call this method several time more and the call back is not working properly.

I'm a JS newbie guy, I expected that it will work like a mutex. Is this actually possible to implement in JS or am I building something this completely wrong.
I plan to do it using only vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do. Please correct me if I am wrong.
Yes, we can wait for Storage.getItem before processing other code. But, for this we need to use async-await when calling getItem.

Please check this code:

```
var Storage = function() {};
Storage.prototype.getItem = function(key) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //Fetch your item here and resolve the value. setTimeout is just for example.
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Some value goes here.");
    }, 2000);
  });
  return promise;
};
(async function() {
  var storage = new Storage();
  console.log("I am called BEFORE Storage.getItem");
  var item = await storage.getItem("key");
  console.log(item);
  console.log("I am called AFTER Storage.getItem");

  console.log("Storage.getItem second time");
  item = await storage.getItem("key");
  console.log(item);

  //do something else
})();
```

This is not going to wait for Storage.getItem:

```
var storage = new Storage();
console.log("I am called BEFORE Storage.getItem");
var item = storage.getItem("key");
console.log(item);
console.log("I am called AFTER Storage.getItem");
```

Please check @ CodePen https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/5a295fc445f97022b75c37189bf875fd

---

<strike>I cannot test your code.
But, here is what I can understand.
I am assuming that `getValue`'s Promise is resolving properly.
Mistake is with the line: `var value = await getValue();`. Its not waiting for anything because it has nothing to wait. Its getting the Promise object right away.</strike>

So, please try this:

```
    var waitFuntion = (async function () {
        var value;
        await getValue().then(function(_value) {
            value = _value;
        });
        console.log("value="+value);
        return value;
    });
```

This makes sure to wait till `getValue`'s Promise actually resolves the value.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks! But is it actually possible to block the hole `Storage.prototype.getItem` method, so any next call to it will be blocked until the previous call receives his value for corresponding key?